# Create a radius when ever the user set's the location

Tags: java, android, android-location

I want to create a radius of 10 meters using the GPS location.
Below is the code to get the GPS location:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;
// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;
Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude
// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters
// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 1 * 1; // 1 second
// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
this.mContext = context;
getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
try {
locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

// getting GPS status
isGPSEnabled = locationManager
.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
// getting network status
isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
// no network provider is enabled
} else {
this.canGetLocation = true;
if (isNetworkEnabled) {
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
Log.d("Network", "Network");
if (locationManager != null) {
location = locationManager
.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if (location != null) {
latitude = location.getLatitude();
longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
}
}
// if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services


if (isGPSEnabled) {

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
    if (locationManager != null) {
    location = locationManager
    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

}

}
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
asreturn location;
}

/**
* Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
*  app
* */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
if (locationManager != null) {
locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
}
}

**
*  Function to get latitude
* */
public double getLatitude() {
if (location != null) {
latitude = location.getLatitude();
}
// return latitude
return latitude;
}

/**
* Function to get longitude
* */
public double getLongitude() {
if (location != null) {
longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
// return longitude
return longitude;
}

/**
* Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
*  
* @return boolean
* */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
return this.canGetLocation;
}


}
```

Comment: Is **radius** your custom way to say **circle**?

Comment: yes, im trying to create a circle using the lat and long as center